# NextJS12 production build errors on module not found

Tags: npm, next.js

**OS**: Windows 10
**Node**: 16.13.0
**NextJS**: 12

I just upgraded to nextjs 12 and am now getting `Module not found` on a `next build`

This is working fine
`next -p 3000`

But when I run `next build` things seems to be compiling but right at the end it fails with the following error.

```
> next build
...

info  - Creating an optimized production build .Warning: 4 repetitive deprecation warnings omitted.

info  - Creating an optimized production build
Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './C:/Users/X/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/next/dist/client/next.js' in 'F:\myproject\x\client'

> Build failed because of webpack errors
```

Since it's complaining about next.js I don't think it has anything to do with any of my other libraries? My application is running fine in nextjs dev mode.

Comment: Try `npm i` again to reinstall all dependencies, then build again.

Comment: Delete `.next` and `node_modules` directories and lock files. Then run `yarn` or `npm i`. If it still doesn't work provide us a minimal, reproducible example and, optionally, create an issue at https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is an actual error. This happened to me once. Just try deleting .next folder first and then run `npm run build`. If that didn't work, try deleting node_modules folder and run `npm install` again.

Answer (score 1):

Something like happened to me few days ago.

I resolved this issues by,

1. Delete the `node_modules` folder
2. Delete the `.next` folder
3. Run the command:

   ```
   npm i`and then `npm run build
   ```